# Change admin password in Gitea

Tags: git, gitea

I created an admin user with a password, that contains a special character. Installation of Gitea was successful, but I can't login. I can't get new password, because it says:

> Sorry, Register Mail Confirmation has been disabled.

I tried command `gitea admin change-password`, but command is not recognized.

Comment: For example, can you try running `gitea admin change-password --username myusername --password asecurenewpassword`, replacing `myusername` with your `user name` value.

Comment: I got error: `gitea admin change-password`

Comment: Are you running that from a terminal? Can you specify which OS are you using?

Comment: Yes, I issued command from Terminal. I use `Ubuntu 17.10 x64`.

Comment: If that is the full error that you are having then your installation is broken...I strongly recommend you to purge your current install and do a clean one.

Comment: I made it again by this tutorial: https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-from-binary/ , but got the same situation. It seems there aren't any package with name `gitea` installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166083/discussion-between-plaidshirt-and-hackerman).

Comment: I was reading the documentation and installing gitea is a real PITA...I sugest you to install Gitlab https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu

Comment: Maybe yes, but its system requirements are lower than Gitlab's.

Comment: You had selected the right answer before, what happened?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the future now and the other answers will no longer work. I found this answer because I had the same problem. I know I will mess this up again as this is already my second time, so hello future me!

Non-docker answer:

```
gitea admin user change-password -u <username> -p <password>
```

Docker answer:

```
docker exec -it <container ID> su git bash -c "gitea admin user change-password -u <username> -p <password>"
```

Replace `<container ID>`, `<username>` and `<password>` with the appropriate values.

[Relevant Gitea Documentation](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/command-line/#admin)

Comment: @Magnetron No. That is not correct. Here is the example from the [Gitea Docs](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/command-line/#admin): 
`gitea admin user change-password --username myname --password asecurepassword`

Comment: @TrevorVance sorry, you're right, I was using an old version

Answer (score 16):

From [your issue](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/3603), any gitea command (like `gitea admin change-password --username myusername --password asecurenewpassword`) ends up with:

```
gitea: command not found
```

If you [installed from binary](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-from-binary/), you will note that the $PATH was not modified, and `gitea` was called directly from its installation folder.

```
./gitea web
```

So you can do the same for changing the password:

```
cd /path/to/gitea
./gitea admin change-password --username myusername --password asecurenewpassword
```

Note that [Robert Ranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5280055/robert-ranjan) adds in the comments:

> `/path/to/gitea` is gitea's home path, where you find folder `custom`.
>   In my case gitea's home is `/var/lib/gitea`. From this path, you should see file: `custom/conf/app.ini` which is expected by default.

Comment: `cd /path/to/gitea` is gitea's home path, where you find folder `custom`. In my case gitea's home is `/var/lib/gitea`. From this path, you should see file: `custom/conf/app.ini` which is expected by default.

Comment: @RobertRanjan OK, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC : I got error message: `models.SetEngine: Failed to connect to database: Unknown database type: 2019/07/17 10:57:10 [I] XORM Log Mode: Console(Info)`

Comment: @plaidshirt maybe Rendy's answer below can help? If not, it would be best to open a new question.

Comment: @VonC : I opened new one, because it still persists.

Answer (score 9):

For Current GITEA sometime it will not work by

```
cd /path/to/gitea
./gitea admin change-password --username myusername --password asecurenewpassword
```

You need to specify the configuration also e.g. :

```
cd /path/to/gitea
./gitea admin change-password --username myusername --password asecurenewpassword -c "/etc/gitea/app.ini"
```

Answer (score 4):

For NixOS users, it's a bit more complicated:

```
su
su gitea
nix-shell -p gitea
gitea admin user change-password -c /var/lib/gitea/custom/conf/app.ini -u user-name -p new-pwd
```

(tested on Gitea version 1.15.6)

Answer (score 2):

When using a dockerized gitea service, you will have to execute the `gitea admin ...` command inside the container as `git` user instead of `root`:

```
docker exec -it <container ID> su git bash -c "gitea admin change-password --username <username> --password <password>"
```

Replace `<container ID>`, `<username>` and `<password>` with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 2):

(docker swarm)

- `docker exec` ( or ssh or however you get to shell
- inner command for reset `gitea -c /etc/gitea/app.ini admin admin change-password --username <username> --password <password>`
- inner command for list  `gitea -c /etc/gitea/app.ini admin user list`